# Will GTX 750 Ti be able to run UHD @ 60Hz on PCIe 2.0 slot?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, displayport, 4k-resolution

I'm wondering if [this card](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAGSC8CE4517) will be able to play UHD@60Hz content utilizing the built-in display port under my PCIe slot running at 2.0 speeds?

NVIDIA's [specs sheet](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti/specifications) outline the following for display support:
**Display Support:**
4 displaysMulti Monitor
**4096x2160 Maximum Digital Resolution**
2048x1536 Maximum VGA Resolution
Yes: HDCP
Yes: HDMI
One Dual Link DVI-I, One Dual Link DVI-D, One mini-HDMI Standard Display Connectors
InternalAudio Input for HDMI

So far, I've been able to confirm that this card can in fact render UHD quality, however it won't go as far as 60Hz with HDMI. I've been told that this may be possible with display port instead. However, this was under the assumption that it was functioning under the prescribed slot (i.e. PCIe 3.0).

Given that my board only has one PCIe 16x16 slot running at 2.0 speeds, is this still achieveable or will I have to buy another card?

P.S. - I don't plan to play games at 4k quality. I've already had it confirmed that this card is way out of its league. Instead, I want to confirm that I can at least watch content that's rendering at 4k UHD quality with 60FPS.

Comment: In a case like this, your display is your primary performance bottleneck, other then your display the cable you use will also be a factor.

Comment: @Ramhound Sounds good. I've been tipped off that the version being used for the Display Port is 1.2. I can't confirm that on EVGA's end, so I might have to check out on a forum or ask some NVIDIA folk. I don't have the budget for a 4k monitor but I plan to get one eventually. It'd be nice to at least keep my current video card though. Thanks for the tip.